# ReactJS/D3 - Use .selectAll on a different component from which D3 is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I need to get some elements from my `d3` code on another component and I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm not really sure if I'm approaching this properly but here's what I have so far.

On my `helpers.tsx` I have this

```
const createStack = (
  chart: d3.Selection<SVGGElement, unknown, null, undefined>,
  dataset: Dataset[],
  stackSeries: d3.Series<
    {
      [key: string]: number
    },
    string
  >[],
  area: d3.Area<[number, number]>,
  line: any
) => {
  let stack = chart.append('g').attr('class', 'stack')
  let colorMap = new Map()
  dataset.forEach((set) => {
    colorMap.set(set.id, set.color)
  })

  stack
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(stackSeries)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', css.stack)
    .attr('fill', (d: any) => {
      return colorMap.get(d.key) + '30'
    })
    .attr('d', (d: any) => area(d))

  chart
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(stackSeries)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', css.line)
    .attr('stroke', (d: any) => {
      return colorMap.get(d.key)
    })
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('d', (d: any) => line(d))
    .on('mouseover', function (d: any, i) {
      d3.select(this).style('stroke-width', '10px')
      something()
      console.log(d.srcElement.__data__.key)
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d: any, i) {
      d3.select(this).style('stroke-width', '1px')
    })
}
```

And I would like to use `.selectAll` on another component so that I can do this part in there

```
    .on('mouseover', function (d: any, i) {
      d3.select(this).style('stroke-width', '10px')
      something()
      console.log(d.srcElement.__data__.key)
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d: any, i) {
      d3.select(this).style('stroke-width', '1px')
    })
```

Would this be possible at all? I've tried it but I can't seem to get any elements at all (could be possibly due to the fact that I'm trying to retrieve the elements before they exist?)

Comment: If you think it's a lifecycle problem, please reproduce the lifecycle for us. We can't evaluate that like this. Reduce your code to a [mre], that will help us understand it

Comment: Probably you can use a [React ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)